# Append content from one file to another in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, concatenation

I have two files, `file1` on server 1 and `file2` on server 2.

Now I want to write a script to append the contents of `file2` (from server 2) to `file1` (on server 1), that is, without overwriting the original contents.

How can I do this with a shell script (using Ubuntu Linux)?

Comment: what do you mean file1 is in server1? they're on different machines? you might want to copy file2 to server1 first, and then `cat file2 >> file1`

Comment: I wanted to write a script. In that there is a case when i wanted to copy the content from one file to another file in another server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssh server2 "cat /path/to/file2" | ssh server1 "cat >> /path/to/file1"
```

If minimizing network traffic is an issue, use the trickier-to-quote version:

```
ssh server2 'cat /path/to/file2 | ssh server1 "cat >> /path/to/file2"'
```

The first version transfers the file to your local host, then to `server1`. The second version transfers the file directly from `server2` to `server1`. (If either file path contains spaces, the quoting becomes much trickier.)